# Can't solve an error "✖ Database connection failed! Check your typeORM config file. "

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, amazon-rds, typeorm

I’m trying to connect to RDS and seed data.

**ormconfig.js**

```js
const entities = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? ['./src/**/**/*.ts'] : ['./dist/**/**/*.js'];
const logging = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test';

module.exports = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'rds.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db',
    synchronize: true,
    migrationsRun: false,
    logging,
    migrations: [`${__dirname}/dist/migration/*.js`],
    entities,
};
// # sourceMappingURL=ormconfig.js.map
```

---

**Error**

> ✖ Database connection failed! Check your typeORM config file.

RDS is running for sure and all the values of DB are from AWS Secrets Manager, so they are correct.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you find a non-useless error message in some log file?  You could check the database's log file (but if you never contacted the correct database system in the first place, its log file wouldn't have an entry about it)

Comment: heu did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: typeorm-seed doesn't support one-to-many, many-to-one relationships well. I just include entities which need to seed, in separate config file.